# Union two different tables with a primary ID field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables

```
MD_Master  (Medical checks)
Id
...

CD_Personal (Personal Checks)
Id
...
```

Each fieldname in both tables are different names, types, and data.

However, each has a Primary Key `Id`, and  can potentially conflict with eath other.

i.e. `Id` `101` can exist in both `MD_Master` and `CD_Personal`

I would like to create a view combing both tables (combining `MD_Medical` and `CD_Personal` `Id` fields) but I don't know how to handle the `Id`s.

I would like the view to have a `Numeric(19,0)` for `Id`.

Would it be possible to select and do a union of these two diffeent tables and create a unique ID?

Thanks

Comment: do you just want an identifier to see which row comes from `Medical` and which one comes from `personal`?  Can you post the table structures and some sample data?

Comment: not clear at all (at my poor eyes). Is there a relation between the two tables? You want a view or a new table (you speak of an Id field) ? You speak of two different tables and UNION, which is rather... problematic...

Comment: We are trying to create a view to match a view used in a web portal, therefore the new view has to have an id field - numeric(19,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
declare @medical table(id int, checks varchar(10))

declare @personal table(id int, checks varchar(10))

insert into @medical 
select 1, 'abc1'
union
select 2, 'abc2'

insert into @personal
select 1, 'abc1'
union
select 2, 'abc22'

;WITH CTE AS (
select *, 'M' As Src from @medical 
union
select *, 'P' As Src from @personal
)

SELECT checks, src, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by checks, id) new_id FROM CTE
```

In your case:

```
SELECT checks, src, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [checks], id) new_id 
FROM 
(

SELECT id, [Medical checks] Checks, 'M' as Src FROM MD_Master
UNION ALL
SELECT id, [Personal checks] Checks, 'P' as Src FROM CD_Personal

)
```

Comment: We are trying to create a view to match a view used in a web portal, therefore the new view has to have an id field - numeric(19,0)

Comment: did you test above query? it is generating new_id that is numeric. DO you want to keep same ids from both table or generate new?

Comment: Generate new or keep the same with something appended to it to differentiate them - i will try your SQL now, but im having a hard time understanding it

Comment: check my updated answer above, i added another sql statement that should be similar to your table schemas

Comment: Got it! - Just had tochange the selects alittle <smile> - thanx

Comment: Ah, i jumped the gun, that won't go into a VIEW. CREATE VIEW View_CR AS

Answer (score 3):

It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do here but you can create an identifier on each row similar to this:

```
SELECT Id, 'M' as tbl
FROM MD_Master
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, 'P' as tbl
FROM CD_Personal
```

This will allow you to distinguish between each row, by seeing which table the record came from.  Then if you have records with the same `ID` you will know what table is came from.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can concatenate the ID with something to stop conflict? You can parse it back out again if necessary, i.e....

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, ID) + 'MD', FirstName, LastName, DOB FROM MD_Master
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, ID) + 'CD', FirstName, LastName, DOB FROM CD_Personal
```

What are you trying to do with the data afterwards?

Comment: We are trying to create a view to match a view used in a web portal, therefore the new view has to have an id field - numeric(19,0)