# Subquery with aggregate function in a union

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am building upon a SQl statement from the following post: [Union two different tables with a primary ID field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285366/union-two-different-tables-with-a-primary-id-field)

There are two tables (md_master & cd_personal_checks) that I am trying to union into one view.
Here is my current statement.

```
CREATE VIEW ViewCR AS  

SELECT id  + 100000000000000000 AS id, a.external_code + CAST(id AS varchar(15)) as crUniqueId,
       m.check_amount, 'C' as crType, m.postprint_date as activationDate,
       m.postprint_date as creationDate, m.memo_explanation as reasonLine1, m.check_no
  FROM MD_Master m
  Join accounts a on m.account_tag = a.acct_id
 WHERE (m.postprint_tag = 2) OR (m.postprint_tag = 4) OR 
       (m.postprint_tag = 5) OR (m.postprint_tag = 7)

 UNION ALL 

SELECT id + 200000000000000000 as id, 'PERCHK' + CAST(id AS varchar(15)) as crUniqueId,
       check_amount, 'P' as crType, business_date as activationDate,
       business_date as creationDate, identify_description as reasonLine1, check_no
  FROM cd_personal_checks
```

HOWEVER, I have reached another obstacle. I need to get data from another table (which has a link to each of the two tables mentioned above)

In both select statments above I need to add a field called "dispositionAmount" which is the check_amount - SUM(md_cr_pending.current_amount)

`md_cr_pending` table has a `master_id` field that links with `md_master.id`
`md_cr_pending` table has a `cd_personal_check_id` field that links with `cd_personal_checks.id`

Thanks for any help

Comment: posting the third table sturcture and the references would make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not post the third table and the forignKeys I only can help with this:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewCR AS  

    SELECT id  + 100000000000000000 AS id, 
    a.external_code + CAST(id AS varchar(15)) as crUniqueId, 
    m.check_amount, 
    'C' as crType, 
    m.postprint_date as activationDate, 
    m.postprint_date as creationDate, 
    m.memo_explanation as reasonLine1, 
    m.check_no,
    m.check_amount - sh.sumAmount As Difference 
    FROM MD_Master m
    Join accounts a on m.account_tag = a.acct_id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT forignKeyID, 
                SUM(md_cr_pending.current_amount) as sumAmount 
                FROM Table 3
                Group BY forignKeyID) sh ON sh.forignKeyID = m.ID
    WHERE (m.postprint_tag = 2) OR (m.postprint_tag = 4) OR 
          (m.postprint_tag = 5) OR (m.postprint_tag = 7)

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT id + 200000000000000000 as id, 
    'PERCHK' + CAST(id AS varchar(15)) as crUniqueId, 
    check_amount, 
    'P' as crType, 
    business_date as activationDate, 
    business_date as creationDate, 
    identify_description as reasonLine1, 
    check_no,
    check_amount - sh.sumAmount As Difference 
    FROM cd_personal_checks 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT forignKeyID, 
                SUM(md_cr_pending.current_amount) as sumAmount 
                FROM Table 3
                Group BY forignKeyID) sh 
                ON sh.forignKeyID = cd_personal_checks.ID
```

Comment: Not sure i quite understand your answer, but I replaced table 3 with md_cr_pending. is that correct? Also, i can't quite figure out what the foreignkeyID is.

Comment: The reference between the tables. The connection what you called "link"

Comment: Couple changes to my field names to replace your  Table3 and ForeignKeyId and it worked!  Thanks!